# Text index to Html index

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to ask if there is a quick way I to find the index of a word in an html element from its plain text index?
lets say I have the following:

```
innerHTML = <span>Hello</span><br><span>World!</span>
innerText = Hello \n World!
```

suppose I want to find the index of word "World" in innerHTML where all I know is its begin and end index in innerText.

**Edit**

Actually I am trying to replace some wrong words in am html text but keeping their styles and structure, for example if a word is in an span element I want to change it without affecting anything else

Comment: What do you mean by "its plain text index"?

Comment: just it's index in the innerText for example the index of "world" is 9

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y question where you're asking about your own solution to a problem, instead of the problem itself. What's the larger issue you're trying to fix?

Comment: If I understood correctly you can do `innerText.split(/\s+/).indexOf("World!")` which returns 1.

Comment: if you only replace wrong words i think it will not affect having html in the strings as it will not change indexes and will not be replaced unless you want to change word span to xyz or br to xyz

Comment: I want to wrap the wrong word inside a span element so I can highlight it and add suggestions for correction.

Comment: you can simply `.replace('wrongword', '<span class='error'>wrong word</span>')` and reassign the `innerHTML` or use a regex if you need to replace it globally.